# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm currently learning Javascript/Node.js/MEAN stack and I'm following an Express tutorial.

I get the following error:

> (node:11524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
>   (node:11524) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

When I hit this route in my browser.

```
function router(nav) {
adminRouter.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
        const dbName = 'libraryApp';

        (async function mongo() {
            let client;
            try {
                client = await mongoClient.connect(url);
                debug('Connected correctly to server');

                const db = client.db(dbName);

                const response = await db.collection('books').insertMany(books);
                res.json(response);
            } catch (err) {
                debug(err.stack);
            }
            client.close();
        }());
    });

return adminRouter;
```

}

Could someone point out the issue and explain what the issue is please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line rejects:

```
 client = await mongoClient.connect(url);
```

Then, you go to your `catch` block and after that catch block, you call `client.close()`.  But, `client` is `undefined` so `client.close()` will throw and you are not inside any sort of `try/catch` at that point.  Since you're inside an `async` function, that throw will turn into a rejected promise which you have no `.catch()` to handle.  Thus, you end up with an unhandled promise rejection.

You should be able to fix it like this:

```
function router(nav) {
    adminRouter.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
        const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
        const dbName = 'libraryApp';

        let client;
        try {
            client = await mongoClient.connect(url);
            debug('Connected correctly to server');

            const db = client.db(dbName);

            const response = await db.collection('books').insertMany(books);
            res.json(response);
        } catch (err) {
            debug(err.stack);
            // make sure and send some response on errors
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        if (client) {
            client.close();
        }
    });
    return adminRouter;
}
```

This makes several changes:

1. Add `if (client)` before calling `client.close()` to protect it from the case where `client never got set.
2. Make the whole `.get()` callback be `async` rather then using an IIFE (not required, just seems cleaner to me)
3. Send an error status and response in your `catch` statement so you are always sending an http response of some kind, even in error situations.

---

If you really wanted to be fail-safe, you could just add another try/catch:

```
function router(nav) {
    adminRouter.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
        const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
        const dbName = 'libraryApp';

        let client;
        try {
            client = await mongoClient.connect(url);
            debug('Connected correctly to server');

            const db = client.db(dbName);

            const response = await db.collection('books').insertMany(books);
            res.json(response);
        } catch (err) {
            debug(err.stack);
            // make sure and send some response on errors
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        try {
            if (client) {
                client.close();
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("unable to close database connection");
        }
    });
    return adminRouter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Once I get back to my machine I'll have a look at making the changes.

But from what you are saying regarding the -

> client = await mongoClient.connect(url);

Is this possibly that my mongo DB isn't up and running correctly or I've not connected to it properly. 

If I had this running properly I wouldn't get the reject?